# Peeking past end-of-file with SICStus Prolog

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, sicstus-prolog

Suppose I have an empty file (imaginatively called `empty`) in the current directory and run the following query.

Using SICStus Prolog 4.7.1 (Intel x86-64):

```
| ?- open(empty,read,S,[eof_action(eof_code)]), 
     stream_property(S,end_of_stream(EOS0)),
     peek_char(S,_), stream_property(S,end_of_stream(EOS1)),
     get_char(S,_),  stream_property(S,end_of_stream(EOS2)),
     peek_char(S,_), stream_property(S,end_of_stream(EOS3)),
     peek_char(S,_), stream_property(S,end_of_stream(EOS4)),
     close(S).
S = '$stream'(140253160396048),
EOS0 = not,
EOS1 = at,
EOS2 = past,
EOS3 = at,
EOS4 = at ?
```

With `peek_char` and `get_char` the stream property `end_of_stream` goes from `not` to `at` to `past`—I get *that*.

But another `peek_char` makes it step *back* from `past` to `at`—That got me:)

What's going on? I was expecting the property to remain at `past`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug.

Once a stream has reached past-end-of-stream (`EOS2`) it remains there (7.10.2.9) unless `eof_action(reset)` is used (7.10.2.11), which it is not in your example so `EOS3` and `EOS4` are wrong. The paragraph numbering is from the ISO Prolog standard.

The bug is present in 4.7.1 (and likely for all earlier releases), for both text and binary streams. <s>I will try to fix this for forthcoming 4.8.</s> This has been fixed in forthcoming 4.8.